# React and TypeScript: How to use generics for callback handlers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following Table component in React which I need to implement as generic as possible with TypeScript. While the `TableItem` is required to have a `id` property, it also can have other properties (but instead of using a Record or any, I want to infer the types):

```
import * as React from "react";

export type TableItem = {
  id: string;
};

export type Column = {
  title: string;
  getContent: <T extends TableItem>(tableItem: T) => React.ReactNode; // <--- HOW TO MAKE GENERIC FOR PERSON TYPE IN APP COMPONENT
};

type TableProps = {
  data: any; // <--- HOW TO TYPE AS GENERIC?
  columns: Column[];
};

const Table: React.FC<TableProps> = ({ data, columns }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <th>{columns.map((column: Column) => column.title)}</th>

      {data.map((tableItem: any) => (
        <tr key={tableItem.id}>
          {columns.map((column: Column) => column.getContent(tableItem))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

My question: When using the `Table` component with its columns and its onChange callback handler within each column, I want to be able to have a typed `tableItem` in there. But it's not working as I am expecting:

```
import * as React from "react";

import Table, { Column, TableItem } from "./Table";

type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const COLUMNS: Column[] = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    // NOT WORKING THIS WAY           v
    getContent: (tableItem: TableItem & Person) => {
      return <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{tableItem.name}</span>;
    },
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    // NOT WORKING THIS WAY           v
    getContent: (tableItem: TableItem & Person) => {
      return <span>{tableItem.age}</span>;
    },
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const data: Person[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "David",
      age: 20,
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Fiona",
      age: 24,
    },
  ];

  return <Table data={data} columns={COLUMNS} />;
};

export default App;
```

How can I fix all the code that got comments in the App and Table component? [Full example over here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-bogdan-00p50b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the generic "higher up" on the type definition:

```
export type TableItem = {
  id: string;
};

export type Column<T extends TableItem> = {
  title: string;
  getContent: (tableItem: T) => React.ReactNode;
};

type TableProps<T extends TableItem> = {
  data: T[];
  columns: Column<T>[];
};
```

Unfortunately this means you can no longer use `FC` because the generic definition is going to be on the lambda:

```
const Table = <T extends TableItem>({ data, columns }: TableProps<T>): ReactNode|null => {
  return (
    <table>
      <th>{columns.map((column: Column<T>) => column.title)}</th>

      {data.map((tableItem: T) => (
        <tr key={tableItem.id}>
          {columns.map((column: Column<T>) => column.getContent(tableItem))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
```

In order to use it you can pass the generic parameter:

```
const COLUMNS: Column<Person>[] = [
  {
    title: "Name",

    getContent: (tableItem: Person) => {
      return <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{tableItem.name}</span>;
    },
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    getContent: (tableItem: Person) => {
      return <span>{tableItem.age}</span>;
    },
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const data: Person[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "David",
      age: 20,
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Fiona",
      age: 24,
    },
  ];

  return <Table<Person> data={data} columns={COLUMNS} />;
};
```

however because it's rather obvious from use what that should be in the above case you can omit it and let TypeScript infer it.

Personally I'd define `Person` as `interface Person extends TableItem { /* more props */ }` to make it more explicit but I leaving it as is should also work